# Fiddler gives 411 Error on request to WCF Service PUT/POST

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler

I’m getting a 411 error when I send a request to the following:

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "IncSMS")]
string IncSMS(int ID);
```

Method:

```
public void IncSMS(int ID)
{
    var business =
        (from p in _db.Businesses
            where p.BusinessID == ID
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
    business.SMSHits += 1;
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Can anyone see why I would be getting the error? All the get methods work, I just cant get POST or PUT to work!

Any ideas???

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, I was trying to request a PUT via a browser and that can’t be done. You can test GETs that way but not PUTs. “because by default it will perform a GET”!

In fiddler you simply type `Content-Length: 0` in the “Request Headers” section of the “Request Builder” and it will magically work! As seen near the bottom of this tutorial: http://blog.donnfelker.com/2008/12/04/how-to-rest-services-in-wcf-3-5-part-2-the-post/

Thanks guys,

Mike.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [HTTP Standards](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), 411 means:
10.4.12 411 Length Required

> The server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content-
>   Length. The client MAY repeat the request if it adds a valid
>   Content-Length header field containing the length of the message-body
>   in the request message.

So looks like before you can add data via POST/PUT you'd need to have the length of the data specified.

Comment: I have found lots of information on that but everyone just says I have to add a content length and you can in most cases get away with Content-Length=0 but how do I do that and what does it mean??? I’m testing with IE and Fiddler but the requests will come from phones. First Android and then I will also need to do the same for Windows and iPhone??? Cheers, Mike.

Comment: When you build the request on the phone, there will be a way to put headers in.  I'm not sure how, because I haven't done phone development.  But it will most likely be some kind of collection of headers in your request object.  You'll place the content-length there.

Answer (score 1):

POST and PUT operations in WCF REST services require that a `Content-Length` header be included. The 411 response code is WCF telling you to include that header.